# MSBuild crashes randomly with Access Violation error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am trying build a couple of projects by using the MSBuild but I am getting the below errors randomly. I am using VS 2015. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
Faulting application name: MSBuild.exe, version: 4.0.30319.33440, time stamp: 0x520045ea
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18696, time stamp: 0x5915ecd6
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0004a034
Faulting process id: 0x1f10
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3020151c2daec
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: e1d83315-6df4-11e7-827b-30f7722873ac
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Application: MSBuild.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.NativeMethodsShared.GetFileAttributesEx(System.String, Int32, WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.FileState.EnsurePopulated()
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.FileState.get_FileExists()
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.IsMatchingSizeAndTimeStamp(Microsoft.Build.Tasks.FileState, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.FileState)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.DoCopyIfNecessary(Microsoft.Build.Tasks.FileState, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.FileState, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CopyFileWithState)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.Execute(Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CopyFileWithState)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26, Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<InitializeAndExecuteTask>d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<InitializeAndExecuteTask>d__24, Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<InitializeAndExecuteTask>d__24 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.InitializeAndExecuteTask(Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.String>, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<ExecuteBucket>d__19.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<ExecuteBucket>d__19, Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<ExecuteBucket>d__19 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteBucket(Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.String>)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<ExecuteTask>d__18.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<ExecuteTask>d__18, Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<ExecuteTask>d__18 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteTask(Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Lookup)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<ExecuteTask>d__13.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<ExecuteTask>d__13, Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<ExecuteTask>d__13 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteTask(Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TargetLoggingContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BuildRequestEntry, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITargetBuilderCallback, Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectTargetInstanceChild, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Lookup, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Lookup, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TargetEntry+<ProcessBucket>d__48.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TargetEntry+<ProcessBucket>d__48, Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<ProcessBucket>d__48 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TargetEntry.ProcessBucket(Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskBuilder, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TargetLoggingContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Lookup, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Lookup)
```

Any suggestion would be of great help.

Thanks,
Anish

Comment: How did you build your project with MSBuild? In other words, what is your build command line? Make sure the MSBuild.exe which you are using is comes from "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin" rather than "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319". Besies, how about the result when you build the project with Visual Studio?

Comment: Virus scanner disabled?

Comment: run msbuild/visual studio as admin. looks like you don't have permissions.

Comment: I even tried to run via "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin" MSBuild.exe but same issue is coming. Also same problem exists while running in Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried to run in "MSBuild Command Promt VS2015" with admin privleges but still the same problem exists.

Comment: According to the error log, it seems the exception code 0xc0000005 is related to access violation. You may need to check the permission of your account and try to repair/reinstall VS.